# How to get the scroll position of a specific content in a repeating div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Is there any way to find the scroll position of a specific content in a div.
I have a chat application running on Angularjs using ng-repeat to display the name and message of the sender.

Here is the HTML code for displaying the message.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in list" >
     <div ng-init="compare(value.name,key,value.date);">
          <div id="date" ng-if="date[key]=='not_same'" >  {{value.date|convert }} </div>
          <div id="recipent" >  
            <div ng-if="name[key]=='not_same'">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ></span> :<b> {{value.name}}</b>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="msgInfo" ng-if="value.name=='Yash'" align='right' >
            <div id="msg" > <b id="ms"> {{value.msg}}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b id="time">{{value.time|change_time}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div>
      </div> 
      <div class="msgInfo" ng-if="value.name!=='Yash'" align='left' >
            <div id="msg" > <b id="ms"> {{value.msg}}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b id="time">{{value.time|change_time}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div>
      </div>   
</div>
```

Here the div id="msg" contains the message.

I also have a "Load previous Messages" button to load the previous messages.
When i click the Load prev Msg button it loads the previous messages and displays in a chronological order. I want to display the oldest message that was present before the previous messages loaded like you seen in Whatsapp.

I use this code to get the content of the specific message

```
var msg=document.getElementById("ms").innerHTML;
```

I want to get the Scroll position of that specific message after the old messages have also been displayed.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the code `Load previous Messages` .... make this first line to get

```
var position = document.getElementById('ms').scrollTop;
```

And when you are finished with loading previous messages, scroll to that message having position `position`

Comment: Actually this code only gets the content of the first message. when i press the load more messages button more messages come above the first message. Value of 'position' always has value = 0

Comment: initially the messages are not loaded so the value of position is set to 0, what i want is to get hte position after the messages are loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".scrolltodiv").offset().top},
    'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $t = $('.scrollContent');
$t.animate({ "scrollTop": $('.scrollContent')[0].scrollHeight }, "fast");
```